# Finding related keywords

Tags: web-scraping

I want to find some data sources from where I can scrape many keywords related to a specified technology.

Suppose, I want to search for java,
I want to get technology keywords related to java. e.g. spring, maven, hibernate etc.

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36710416/363573