# How to access the subclass using jsoup

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I want to access this webpage: https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=ice%20cream and extract the data within in the center line graph. The html file is(Here, I only paste the part that I use.):

```
  <div class="center-col">
       <div class="comparison-summary-title-line">...</div>
       ...
       <div id="reportContent" class="report-content">
            <!-- This tag handles the report titles component -->
       ...
       <div id="report">
         <div id="reportMain">
           <div class="timeSection">
              <div class = "primaryBand timeBand">...</div>
                  ...
                 <div aria-lable = "one-chart" style = "position: absolute; ...">
                 <svg ....>
                 ...
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                 var chartData = {...}
```

And the data I used is stored in the script part(last line). My idea is to get the class "report-content" first, and then select script. And my code follows as:

```
  String html = "https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=ice%20cream";
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();

  Elements center = doc.getElementsByClass("center-col");
  Element report = doc.getElementsByClass("report-content");

  System.out.println(center);
  System.out.println(report);
```

When I print "center" class, I can get all the subclasses content except the "report-content", and when I print the "report-content", the result is only like:

```
      <div id="reportContent" Class="report-content"></div>
```

And I also try this:

```
  Element report = doc.select(div.report-content).first();
```

but still does not work at all. How could I get the data in the script here? I appreciate your help!!!

Comment: See [Fetch contents(loaded through AJAX call) of a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633294/fetch-contentsloaded-through-ajax-call-of-a-web-page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this url instead:

```
https://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en&q=${keywords}&tz=${timezone}&content=1
```

where

- `${keywords}` is an encoded space separated keywords list
- `${timezone}` is an encoded timezone in the Etc/GMT* form

[DEMO](http://try.jsoup.org/%7EviJGGnq4Q0fGrimx78Rc04v5MUo)

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String myKeywords = "ice cream";
String myTimezone = "Etc/GMT+2";

String url = "https://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en&q=" + URLEncoder.encode(keywords, "UTF-8") +"&tz="+URLEncoder.encode(myTimezone, "UTF-8")+"&content=1";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).get();
Element scriptElement = doc.select("div#TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0-time-chart + script").first();

if (scriptElement==null) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate trends data.");
}

String jsCode = scriptElement.html(); 
// parse jsCode to extract charData...
```

References:

- [How to extract the text of a `<script>` element with Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873805/363573)

Comment: Thank you so much! It is amazing~~!

Answer (score 0):

Trying getting the same by Id, you would get the complete tag

Comment: Thank you! When I use "doc.select(div.reportContent)", which is the id, the result is null. When I use "doc.select(div.report-content)", which is the class, the result is <div...></div> without the content. And then I cannot get the script within this class either.

Comment: did you try getElementById("reportMain")?